# Why would setTimeout def.reject code not run if the sendToSocket succeeds?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why would `setTimeout` `def.reject` code not run if the sendToSocket succeeds?

```
this.send = function(type, body) {
    var def = Promise.defer();
    try{
        sendToSocket({...});
        setTimeout(function() { // if the send sendToSocket Succeeds how does nodejs/javascript know not to run the timeout code after 10 seconds?
            def.reject(new Error("timeout"));
        }, 10000);
    }catch(err){
        logger.error('error');
        def.reject(err);
    }

    return def.promise;
};
```

Comment: a Promise can only be resolved once (in this case I'm using the word resolve to mean either fulfill on success or reject on error) ... once resolved, any attempt to reject or fulfill is silently ignored - therefore the timeout **will always run to completion**, but if the Promise has already been fulfilled, the reject wont effect the Promise - read section 2.1 in the spec - https://promisesaplus.com/

Comment: @JaromandaX what if i add some `log` printing just before the `def.reject` inside teh `setTimeout` would it be run if the sendToSocket passes successfully before 10 seconds have passed if not - which is what i think, what is the reason it would not get run?

Comment: `what if i add some log printing just before the def.reject inside teh setTimeout` - do it and see - it should log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment said, a Promise's state may only be changed once, from pending to either fulfilled or rejected. Once the promise had been fulfilled, the rejection will be ignored.

In addition, it's considered better form to **not** use `Promise.defer()` and instead use the `new Promise` constructor:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    sendToSocket({...}); // call resolve() here
    setTimeout(function() { reject(new Error("timeout")); }, 10000)
});
```

You'll notice that there's no `try/catch` here, that's because inside the Promise constructor, any thrown exception is automatically converted to a rejection for you.

---

*Another* thing I would do, is separate the method from the timeout, something like this:

```
function withTimeout(delay, fn) {
    return function() {
        return Promise.race([ // race between...
            // Promise that rejects after "delay" ms
            new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function() { reject(new Error("timeout")); }, delay);
            }), // and...
            // Promise that actually does the action

            // The call to `Promise.resolve()` is to ensure we get a Promise
            // even if the function doesn't return one.
            Promise.resolve(fn.apply(null, arguments))
        ]);
    };
}

this.send = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sendToSocket({...}); // call resolve here, or reject on error.
                             // thrown errors will be converted anyway
    });
};

this.sendWithTimeout = withTimeout(10000, this.send.bind(this));
```

Calling `withTimeout` will return a *new function*, that returns a Promise with the timeout option.

`Promise.race()` returns a Promise that resolves (or rejects) when the first Promise out of the passed array of Promises resolves or rejects. We're *racing* between the actual promise returned from `this.send()` and a promise that would reject on timeout.

This means that your `this.send()` function only deals with actually sending. The timeout is a detail you add via abstraction.

Comment: nice! didn't know about the `.race`!